# How to work on finding the decibels of a sound

Tags: acoustics

How exactly would I go about finding the sound of something based on comparisons. For instance, what would the decibel level of footsteps to sound like thunderclaps, I know that thunder can be around 120 dB, footsteps, from what I can find, seem to be between 50-60 tops.

That is to say, if 55 dB (using average for simplicity) sounds like 120 dB, what would 120 sound like? I know that due to how dB work, it really isn't a subjective thing, this is just to get a sort of comparison.

So mathematically, how would I find the level given this relative comparison, and if you can, give a formula to generalize it more. I mostly just have issues with dB and their logarithmic nature, makes it difficult to calculate. Thanks for your assistance, and I apologize if I am a bother.

**Edit for Clarification:** Basically, apply the difference between 55 and 120, to 120.

Comment: What do you mean by "55 dB sounds like 120 dB"?

Comment: I mean that it sounds as if it is that loud, due to very enhanced hearing. I am simply using decibels as a way to measure it in a way that is more capable of being understood in terms of our own hearing. So basically, it is a non-scientific method, this is moreso just mathematical in nature. <br> So it means that footsteps sound as loud as thunderclaps, so I want to find what decibel level a thunderclap would be, given that a 55 dB sound is sounding like 120. So mathematically, it just means apply the difference between 55 and 120, to 120. (Sorry about explaining poorly)

Comment: I think you can just add it, it will sound like 175dB.

Comment: Be aware that dB is the unit of the sound power flow density. It is objective measurement, with 0 dB equivalent to 10^-12 W/m2. It does not reflect spectral subjective sensitivity of human ears.  The unit of subjective loudness is 1 [Phon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phon), where dB Vs Phon spectral relation is given by empirical subjective measurement.

Comment: I did actively say I knew that, I am using this to find some sort of comparison, to say that it *sounds* like a sound of x dB, not that it *is* one of x dB. There is a difference in those ideas, because yes, I know dB is objective.

Answer (score 0):

A device (whether mechanical or biological) which increases or decreases a sound by a particular number of decibels will increase or decrease all sounds$^1$ by a the same number of decibels. If the device boosts 55dB to 120dB (a +65dB increase), it will boost 120dB to 185dB.

What is really going on is that the device **multiplies** incoming sound **intensity** (power per unit area) by a fixed factor. Decibels are a scale such that a multiplication of sound intensity by 10 corresponds to an absolute increase of 10 decibels and vice versa.

Consider hearing protection. Suppose I wear protective earmuffs that reduce incoming sound by an intensity factor of $10^{-3}$, or -30dB. Under them I wear protective ear plugs that reduce incoming sound by an intensity factor of $10^{-4}$, or -40dB. My total decrease in sound intensity is $10^{-4} \times 10^{-3} = 10^{-7}$, or -70dB.

It seems very unlikely to me that any animal has ears big enough to concentrate enough sound for a 65dB increase in loudness (about 3 million times more sound power reaching the eardrum). It would need to drag around giant radar dish sized ears all day (3 million times larger than human ears, if they concentrate sounds with similar efficiency) and it would quickly go deaf from normal environmental sounds.

---

1- in the case of an amplifier, there's a maximum output power, but all sounds up to that maximum output power will be boosted by the same number of decibels.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense, becuase dB are logarithmic, therefore the difference between 120 and 185 is MUCH bigger than 55 to 120. Like, 60 dB is 1000000x that of 0 dB, and 100 is 10000000000x that of 0, the gaps increase immensely. Therefore it shouldn't increase it by 65 dB as far as I understand it. And on the physical impossibility, I know, it is magically enhanced hearing in the context of what I am talking about, and it is indeed shown as being basically a disability.

Comment: $log(10^x × 10^y) = log10^{x+y}=x+y$

Comment: Yeah, I started to try the math and managed to make out that that is the case, it is just by the time I did that it was past the point that I could edit the comment. Thanks though, you were of great assistance.